# PHP SNMP - Cannot find module

Tags: php, apache, snmp

I've enabled the SNMP module was trying to the functions in the module.  I have set the MIBDIRS environment variable to where I have my mibs but I'm still getting these "Cannot find module" warnings:

```
Cannot find module (IP-MIB): At line 0 in (none)
Cannot find module (IF-MIB): At line 0 in (none)
Cannot find module (TCP-MIB): At line 0 in (none)
Cannot find module (UDP-MIB): At line 0 in (none)
Cannot find module (HOST-RESOURCES-MIB): At line 0 in (none)
Cannot find module (SNMPv2-MIB): At line 0 in (none)
Cannot find module (SNMPv2-SMI): At line 0 in (none)
Cannot find module (NOTIFICATION-LOG-MIB): At line 0 in (none)
Cannot find module (UCD-SNMP-MIB): At line 0 in (none)
Cannot find module (UCD-DEMO-MIB): At line 0 in (none)
Cannot find module (SNMP-TARGET-MIB): At line 0 in (none)
Cannot find module (NET-SNMP-AGENT-MIB): At line 0 in (none)
Cannot find module (DISMAN-EVENT-MIB): At line 0 in (none)
Cannot find module (SNMP-VIEW-BASED-ACM-MIB): At line 0 in (none)
Cannot find module (SNMP-COMMUNITY-MIB): At line 0 in (none)
Cannot find module (UCD-DLMOD-MIB): At line 0 in (none)
Cannot find module (SNMP-FRAMEWORK-MIB): At line 0 in (none)
Cannot find module (SNMP-MPD-MIB): At line 0 in (none)
Cannot find module (SNMP-USER-BASED-SM-MIB): At line 0 in (none)
Cannot find module (SNMP-NOTIFICATION-MIB): At line 0 in (none)
Cannot find module (SNMPv2-TM): At line 0 in (none)
```

I know I have fixed this once but I can't seem to fix it again...what else can I try?

I'm on Windows.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Apparently there are 2 environment variables you can set.  One is `MIBDIRS` which is where all the MIB files are.  Another is `MIBS`, which I believe is which SNMP modules you want to load.  By setting `MIBS` to `ALL`, I was able to get rid of the errors.

Comment: These is similar to the bash environment and net-snmp tools (not sure if they are related to this). Glad you found an answer. :)

Comment: I believe PHP is using Net-SNMP in the back so I suppose it makes sense why it's similar to the net-snmp tools you are familiar with :)

Answer (score 10):

Open your `php.ini` and add some magical semicolon at line that look like:

```
extension=php_snmp.dll
```

It should look like:

```
;extension=php_snmp.dll
```

Comment: That's true if I don't need SNMP but in this case, I actually do.  I think I might have found a way to work around it.  Let me answer my own question.  Thanks!

Comment: Did you see how to install SNMP? Look here http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc759570(v=ws.10).aspx

Comment: Isn't the SNMP service to allow you to do snmpget/snmpwalk on the Windows machine? i.e. to monitor the Windows machine?  If so, that's not what I want to do.  I want to do gets & walks FROM a Windows machine, not TO.

Comment: For me it was the other way around, if I removed the semicolon my ampps localhost magicly works again. Thanks.

Answer (score 10):

I've got the same problem in Ubuntu with php7.1 and the solution was installing snmp package

```
apt-get install snmp
```

Answer (score 6):

On linux, I was able to fix these by adding this to my /etc/php5/apache2/conf.d/snmp.ini file.

mibdir=/usr/share/snmp/mibs
mibs=all

Answer (score 6):

The php package doesn't include mibs folder, what you have to do is download the source file of net-snmp and copy the folder into your php directory

download link
https://sourceforge.net/projects/net-snmp/files/net-snmp/5.7.3/

after that, unzip the zip file and copy the mibs folder to your php directory

for exmaple,copy it to C:\PHP\Extras\mibs
Thne add a new system variable called MIBDIRS. Its value should be: C:\PHP\Extras\mibs

Finally, you can run `php -m`

and you issue will be resoved

I attach a screenshot for your reference.[image]

Comment: I got the same problems in windows 10. It shows like this. 'MIB search path: c:/usr/share/snmp/mibs'. So, I copied the 'Mibs' files into that location. But there are no such location. I have to create share/snmp inside 'c:usr' folder.

Answer (score 2):

I just fixed it on my machine here by adding

```
mibdirs +/var/lib/mibs/iana:/var/lib/mibs/ietf
```

to `/etc/snmp/snmp.conf`.

Answer (score 2):

Faced a similar problem but in Ubuntu -

In /etc/snmp/snmp.conf -

```
# As the snmp packages come without MIB files due to license reasons, loading
# of MIBs is disabled by default. If you added the MIBs you can reenable
# loading them by commenting out the following line.
#mibs :
```

So , commenting out the mibs line in this file solved it .

Answer (score 2):

Stumbled upon this migrating older Cacti to Ubuntu 16.

In Ubuntu/Debian package `php-snmp` depends on `php7.0-snmp`, neither of which come with MIBs or depend on `snmp-mibs-downloader`, hence SNMP module ends up being defunct with no MIBs available.

What you should do is install `snmp-mibs-downloader` (or equivalent) and let it download all available MIBs and see if that helps. If it doesn't, you might need to adjust `mibdirs` in `/etc/php/x.x/mods-available/snmp.ini` and/or manually load required MIBs (loading everything via `mibs = ALL` would work, but I consider it bad practice).

If no downloader is available, follow @Robin's advice and get MIBs from [Net-SNMP](https://sourceforge.net/projects/net-snmp/)

Answer (score 1):

I changed `extension=snmp` to `; extension=snmp` in `php.ini`

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This worked perfectly for me. For people using XAMPP on Windows 10, click "Config" next to Apache service in the XAMPP control panel window to edit the "php.ini" file. Make the suggested changes, then restart the Apache service.