# PHP cant find SNMP modules under Windows 7

Tags: php, snmp, mib

I've enabled the SNMP module was trying to the functions in the module.  I have set the MIBDIRS environment variable to where I have my mibs but I'm still getting these "Cannot find module" warnings:

```
Cannot find module (IP-MIB): At line 0 in (none)
Cannot find module (IF-MIB): At line 0 in (none)
Cannot find module (TCP-MIB): At line 0 in (none)
Cannot find module (UDP-MIB): At line 0 in (none)
Cannot find module (HOST-RESOURCES-MIB): At line 0 in (none)
Cannot find module (SNMPv2-MIB): At line 0 in (none)
Cannot find module (SNMPv2-SMI): At line 0 in (none)
Cannot find module (NOTIFICATION-LOG-MIB): At line 0 in (none)
Cannot find module (UCD-SNMP-MIB): At line 0 in (none)
Cannot find module (UCD-DEMO-MIB): At line 0 in (none)
Cannot find module (SNMP-TARGET-MIB): At line 0 in (none)
Cannot find module (NET-SNMP-AGENT-MIB): At line 0 in (none)
Cannot find module (DISMAN-EVENT-MIB): At line 0 in (none)
Cannot find module (SNMP-VIEW-BASED-ACM-MIB): At line 0 in (none)
Cannot find module (SNMP-COMMUNITY-MIB): At line 0 in (none)
Cannot find module (UCD-DLMOD-MIB): At line 0 in (none)
Cannot find module (SNMP-FRAMEWORK-MIB): At line 0 in (none)
Cannot find module (SNMP-MPD-MIB): At line 0 in (none)
Cannot find module (SNMP-USER-BASED-SM-MIB): At line 0 in (none)
Cannot find module (SNMP-NOTIFICATION-MIB): At line 0 in (none)
Cannot find module (SNMPv2-TM): At line 0 in (none)
```

My php.ini settings are:

```
mibdir=C:\\Users\username\Downloads\Applications\Dev\PHP\5.4\net-snmp-mibs\net-snmp-5.7.2.1\mibs
mibs=all
extension=php_snmp.dll
```

I'm on Windows.

And it still gives those errors...

Any insights please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The PHP docs is misleading for Windows;
In order to get rid of the errors and have SNMP module working properly, you **MUST** add an environment variable in the System, called **MIBDIRS** and pointing to the location of your mib files.

On Windows 7 for example, that would be System Properties > Environment Variables > User variables section, click New and add MIBDIRS, with value of C:\usr\mibs (or wherever you put the mibs folder).

The files should be extracted using a Net-SNMP package, tested with version net-snmp-5.7.2.1 on PHP 5.4.7 using CLI mode.

Answer (score 2):

The php package doesn't include a `mibs` folder, what you have to do is download the source file of net-snmp and copy the folder into your php directory

download link https://sourceforge.net/projects/net-snmp/files/net-snmp/5.7.3/

after that, unzip the zip file and copy the mibs folder to your php directory

for example,copy it to C:\PHP\Extras\mibs
Then add a new system variable called MIBDIRS. Its value should be: C:\PHP\Extras\mibs

Finally, you can run `php -m`

and you issue will be resoved

I attach a screenshot for your reference.[image]

Answer (score 1):

Copied from another post:

Apparently there are 2 environment variables you can set. One is MIBDIRS which is where all the MIB files are. Another is MIBS, which I believe is which SNMP modules you want to load. By setting MIBS to ALL, I was able to get rid of the errors

Comment: For your reference,

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16467712/php-snmp-cannot-find-module

Comment: I am aware of that post, did you fully read my question? in the second half, I stated my php.ini settings:
My php.ini settings are: mibdir=C:\Users\username\Downloads\Applications\Dev\PHP\5.4\net-snmp-mibs\net-snmp-5.7.2.1\mibs mibs=all extension=php_snmp.dll

Comment: Can i know which web server you are using? Xamp or Wamp?

Comment: I am not using any in fact. I have PHP extracted to  C:\Users\username\Downloads\Applications\Dev\PHP\5.4\, and added to my path, so I just use it from command line using php scriptname.php

I currently do not require a web server for my development needs.

Answer (score 1):

Acording to PHP SNMP Instllation page:

> The Windows distribution of Net-SNMP contains support files for SNMP
>   in the mibs directory. This directory should be moved to
>   DRIVE:\usr\mibs, where DRIVE must be replaced with the driveletter
>   where PHP is installed on, e.g.c:\usr\mibs. Alternatively you may set
>   MIBDIRS environment variable pointed to your MIBs folder.

http://php.net/manual/en/snmp.installation.php

Comment: Thanks, I've already been using mibdir setting in php.ini, but I've tried to give this a try, including adjusting the setting to C:\usr\mibs - still no change, php still gives me those "Cannot find module.." errors when calling php from command line.

Comment: Actually, after further reading of the manual you linked to, I realized I misunderstood and confused **php.ini** setting for mibdir=, and the **ENVIRONMENT VARIABLE** called **MIBDIRS**!!
Once I attempted and added the environment variable MIBDIRS in windows (although guide says its for 32bit windows) and re-opened the command line window - no warnings anymore, it works!!!

You sir, earned the 100 bounty points, but I will post a new answer to emphsize the root issue - MIBDIRS environment variable is a MUST, not optional as the docs say...