# what are MIBs in php?

Tags: php, arrays, server, xampp, mib

When I use this code in PHP:

```
print_r($_SERVER);
```

the first index that it prints is:

> [MIBDIRS] => C:/xampp/php/extras/mibs

**Can somebody tell me what is MIB-Directory ? and what is used for ?**

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/snmp.installation.php "The Windows distribution of Net-SNMP contains support files for SNMP in the mibs directory. This directory should added to Windows' environment variables, as MIBDIRS, with the value being the full path to the mibs directory: e.g. c:\usr\mibs."

Answer (score 3):

From my research, I have found:

> *A **management information base** (**MIB**) is a database used for managing the entities in a [communication network](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Communication_network). Most often associated with the [Simple Network Management Protocol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simple_Network_Management_Protocol) (SNMP), the term is also used more generically in contexts such as in [OSI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open_Systems_Interconnection)/[ISO Network management model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open_Systems_Interconnection). While intended to refer to the complete collection of management information available on an entity, it is often used to refer to a particular subset, more correctly referred to as MIB-module.*<sup>[1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Management_information_base)</sup>

There is a PHP package [Net-SNMP](http://www.net-snmp.org/), which when enabled, will allow a user to call functions like [snmp_read_mib()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.snmp-read-mib.php) that will read MIB files.

> #### snmp_read_mib
>
> Reads and parses a MIB file into the active MIB tree
>
> `bool snmp_read_mib ( string $filename )`
>
> This function is used to load additional, e.g. vendor specific, MIBs so that human readable OIDs like VENDOR-MIB::foo.1 instead of error prone numeric OIDs can be used.
>
> The order in which the MIBs are loaded does matter as the underlying Net-SNMP libary will print warnings if referenced objects cannot be resolved.

Note that [$_SERVER](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php) contains environment variables:

> `$_SERVER` -- $HTTP_SERVER_VARS [removed] — Server and execution environment information<sup>[2](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php)</sup>

And in the User Contributed Notes for [snmp_read_mib()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.snmp-read-mib.php), the top post is:

> If you are trying to import mibs with dependencies on other mibs you will have to set the MIBDIRS environment variable.
>
> Unix / Linux: `export MIBDIRS=/home/<user>/MIBS:/usr/share/snmp/mibs`
>   Window: Good luck! No really.  Try this url out.  It has everything that you need to know about setting environment vars in windows.
>
> http://vlaurie.com/computers2/Articles/environment.htm
> <sup>[3](http://php.net/manual/en/function.snmp-read-mib.php#81586)</sup>

I just installed the latest version of (32-bit) XAMPP for Windows with PHP version 7.1.1. Looking in *C:\xampp\apache\conf\extra\httpd-xampp.conf* (one of the main [Apache configuration files](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/configuring.html)) I see on line 6:

```
SetEnv MIBDIRS "C:/xampp/php/extras/mibs"
```

So that sets the environment variable for PHP, which is why you see *MIBDIRS* in $_SERVER.

Perhaps the *MIBDIRS* from $_SERVER would be used like this:

```
snmp_read_mib($_SERVER['MIBDIRS'].'IPV6-TC.txt');
```

I was hoping to see an example in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24627020/1575353) or its answers but didn't see any.

---

<sup>1</sup><sub>https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Management_information_base</sub>

<sup>2</sup><sub>http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php</sub>

<sup>3</sup><sub>http://php.net/manual/en/function.snmp-read-mib.php#81586</sub>